# How can I identify the ID of a specific DIV so I can add background image to it?

Tags: html, css, joomla, background-image, joomla-template

I bought a Joomla template but I don't have a support subscription anymore so I need to modify the styling myself.

1. I want to change the background of the highlighted "violet" on the left side, with an image background.
2. On the left side of the image are the codes.
3. I want to put a CSS override putting an image background.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pVE1.png)

Comment: Please take the [tour] then read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The "violet" div has no id; but its parent does. You do not need an Id to match an element; a unique class / class combination will be enough.
To be on the safe side you could select by parent id followed by the child classes:

```
#gkHeader > .box.mediumspaces.greybg {
  background-image:url(someimage.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

- `#gkHeader`  : the item whose id is gkHeader;
- `>` : the immediate children (direct children of the previous selector)
- `.box.mediumspaces.greybg` : with all the classes separated by dots

Should your child divs have no distinctive class combinations that will allow you to select one, you could still achieve this with a positional selector:

```
#gkHeader > div:nth-child(3)
```

where:

- `#gkHeader > div` selects all direct descendants of `<div id="gkheader">`
- :nth-child(3) selects the third item in the collection

please mind the spaces,

- `.class1 .class2` is selecting an item with `class="class2"` contained in another with `class="class1"`;
- `.class1.class2` is selecting an item with `class="class1 class2"`

If your rule does *not* work, but you see it in the browser inspector, there may be a rule with a more relevant selector; if so, be more specific in your selector (add more parents, or use ids instead of classes), or add `!important` after the style